# Read only default for files

Tags: windows-xp

After choosing to save a document that was emailed to me, the file defaults to a read only version. This didn't happen on my previous laptop. Is there a quick fix so that not every file I choose to save comes up as a read only document?

Comment: What Email client are you using? Word prcessor? file type?

Comment: Are you saving the attachment to the hard drive before opening it?

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems are often cause by attempting to open the file, which downloads them to a temporary folder, and the file in question is marked as read only.

You can choose to:

1. Directly save the file from your email client.
2. Save a copy of the read only file (`File -> Save as` for most document editors)

I would suggest saving the file somewhere in your User folder (for example: Desktop, My Documents, etc.)